# How do I render a more HD picture in blender internal 2.79

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Here the image I obtain:

[image]

Here are rendering options:

[image]

Comment: Just change the resolution X, Y to what you want in the rendering options.

Comment: Please update your question to explain what exactly your trying to achieve and what you've attempted so far to solve the problem. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask